# Concurrent modification exception

Tags: java, android

My following code is throwing concurrent modification exception and I am not able to solve it. Help!

```
  {
    long now = new Date().getTime();
    Set<String> keyset = requests.keySet();
    Iterator<String> iterator = keyset.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String packetId = iterator.next();
        RequestHolder entry = requests.get(packetId);
        if (entry.isExpired(now)) {
            entry.getListener().onTimeout(packetId);
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: why do you need to remove the iterator when you are iterating it?

Comment: I am to remove the element actually. Doing request.remove(iterator.next()) would go wrong.

Comment: What is the class implementation of `keyset` object? Looks like its `iterator` doesn't support concurrent using.

Comment: what is your request object i mean its type ??

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code by

```
long now = new Date().getTime();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, RequestHolder>> iterator = requests.entrySet().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, RequestHolder> entry = iterator.next();
    String packetId = entry.getKey();
    RequestHolder requestHolder = entry.getValue();
    if (requestHolder.isExpired(now)) {
        requestHolder.getListener().onTimeout(packetId);
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

The solution is to iterate over the whole collection and not over the key set, using the key set iterator to access entries from the collection again and removing entries from the key set

Comment: The object "requests" is of type: Map<String, RequestHolder> requests;
And it is not supporting requests.iterator()

Comment: Yes, so it produces an `Iterator<Map.Entry<String, RequestHolder>>` as above said.

Comment: But iterator() method is not available for "requests" object..
Not able to call requests.iterator()

Comment: I'm sorry, consider my edit (I forgot http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your while loop with this one ...

```
for (Entry<String, RequestHolder> entryElem : requests.keySet()) {
            String packetId = entryElem.getValue();
        RequestHolder entry = requests.getValue.get(packetId);
        if (entry.isExpired(now)) {
            entry.getListener().onTimeout(packetId);
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```